# After doing a transform on a Parallax div, My background gradient Isn't covering the whole background

Tags: css, transform, gradient, parallax

I am having a strange styling issue with two divs I am working on in css.

The requirements of these divs is that they must be skewed and translated (which I'm doing through a transform), they must have a gradient on the backgrounds, and the backgrounds must have parallax scrolling.

The issue is that this causes part of the background image to not be affected by the gradient.

The current code I am using on these divs is as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="diag gradient-bg2">
    <div class='diag-wrapper banner3'>
        <h1><?=$banner3Header1?></h1>
        <p><?=$banner3Content1?></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="diag gradient-bg3">
    <div class='diag-wrapper banner4'>
        <h1><?=$banner4Header1?></h1>
        <p><?=$banner4Content1?></p>
        <a class="btn" id="get-started-btn">ASK AN EXPERT</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.diag {
    padding: 5% 20px;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-3deg) translateY(-5vw);
    -moz-transform: skewY(-3deg) translateY(-5vw);
    -ms-transform: skewY(-3deg) translateY(-5vw);
    -o-transform: skewY(-3deg) translateY(-5vw);
    transform: skewY(-3deg) translateY(-5vw) ;

} 
/*this unskews the content in a skewed div. It should be the opposite of above values**/
.diag > .diag-wrapper {
    padding-top:5vh;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(3deg);
    -o-transform: skewY(3deg);
    transform: skewY(3deg);
}
.gradient-bg2{
    margin:0;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.97),rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)), url("../img/mri.png") 50%; 
     height: 100%; 
     background-attachment: fixed;
     background-position: center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
}
.gradient-bg3 { 
    margin:0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right,rgba(11, 179, 199, 1),rgba(154, 202, 73, 0.7)), url("../img/mri2.png"); 
     height: 100%; 
     background-attachment: fixed;
     background-position: right;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size:auto 100%;
}
.banner3{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10vh 20vw 10vh 20vw;
}
.banner4{
    color:white;
    padding-top:10vh;
    padding-bottom:10vh;
    padding-left:16vw;
    padding-right:57vw;
}
```

Something to note is that aside from the gradient error, these divs are functioning exactly as required. Here is a screenshot of what the issue looks like:

[First Div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzi8V.png)

[Second Div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY7yd.png)

Does anybody have any idea what could be causing this issue, and how this issue could be solved?

Comment: Do you expect to see a background _outside_ of the boundaries of an element, or what?

Comment: @misorude That's not what I am expecting. The issue is that while the background is visible inside the boundaries of the element (as intended), the gradient is only affecting a certain part of the background rather than the entire thing. This is best demonstrated by the first image, where you can more clearly see the part of the image that isn't affected by the gradient

Comment: I don’t see how _that_ part of the image shows there in the first place - you skewed the element, so that part of the screen should not be covered by _any_ background, neither gradient nor image, to begin with … unless that’s the same image applied as background to a different, non-skewed container element or something. Can you please show a proper live example of this, including images?

Comment: No, it doesn’t - _because_ you skewed it.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. This discussion has given me the idea to try an alternative method of making the background. If I get it working I will update this post for future niche confusion